# When did 13 years pass in 13 days?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma-shastras, time, prayaschitta, bhima

In [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03052.htm) there is mention that it is written in shastras that there are some special occasions in which 13 years pass in 13 days.

> When the high-souled Partha went to Indra's region for obtaining
>   weapons, those bulls of the Bharata race continued to dwell with
>   Krishna in (the woods of) Kamyaka. One day, those foremost of the
>   Bharatas, afflicted with grief, were seated with Krishna on a clean
>   and solitary sward. Grieving for Dhananjaya, overwhelmed with sorrow,
>   their voices were choked with weeping.
>
> Tortured by Dhananjaya's absence, grief afflicted them equally. And
>   filled with sorrow at their separation from Arjuna and at the loss of
>   their kingdom, the mighty-armed **Bhima** among them **addressed
>   Yudhishthira**, **saying**,
>
> > ...O great king, it is not the duty of a
> >     Khsatriya to live in the woods. The wise are of the opinion that to
> >     rule is the foremost duty of a Kshatriya. O king, thou art conversant
> >     with Kshatriya morality. Do not, therefore, deviate from the path of
> >     duty. Turning away from the woods, let us, summoning Partha and
> >     Janardana, slay, O king, the sons of Dhritarashtra, even before the
> >     twelve years are complete. O illustrious monarch O king of kings, even
> >     if these Dhartarashtras be surrounded by soldiers in array of battle,
> >     I shall send them to the other world by dint of might alone. I shall
> >     slay all the sons of Dhritarashtra along with the Sauvalas, indeed,
> >     Duryodhana, Karna, and any one else that will fight with me. And after
> >     I shall have slain all our foes, thou mayst come back unto the woods.
> >     By acting thus, O king, no fault will be thine. (Or if any sin be
> >     thine), O represser of foes, O mighty monarch, washing it off, O sire,
> >     by various sacrifices, we may ascend to a superior heaven. Such a
> >     consummation may come to pass, if our king proveth not unwise or
> >     procrastinating. Thou art, however, virtuous. Verily the deceitful
> >     should be destroyed by deceit. To slay the deceitful by deceit, is not
> >     regarded as sinful.
> >
> > O Bharata, it is, also said by those versed in morality that **one day
> >     and night is**, O great prince, **equal unto a full year**. The Veda text
> >     also, exalted one, is often heard, signifying that **a year is
> >     equivalent to a day when passed in the observance of certain difficult
> >     vows**. O thou of unfading glory, if the Vedas are an authority with
> >     thee, regard thou the period of a day and something more as the
> >     **equivalent of thirteen years**. O represser of foes, this is the time to
> >     slay Duryodhana with his adherents...

When did it happen in history and what were those special occasions?

Comment: can u add where exactly in MBH it's mentioned..

Comment: @YDS when Pandvas were in forest for 12 years after the game of dice and after 13 days all 4 brothers were ready to return except Yudhisthira. He said one should not mold the shastras for one's own sake.

Comment: I might have added the wrong reference then...if you find the correct reference you can edit your post and add the link.